# Creating a predicate that detects if a list contains repeated elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog, duplicates

I need to define a predicate which detects if a list contains repeated elements. I cannot make use of `findall/3` or related predicates. I do not want to delete the duplicate,  I would like to figure out if there is an element that is repeated or duplicated and then have Prolog output 'yes' if there is a duplicate in a set or 'no' if there is not. I am new to Prolog and I cannot figure out how to do this without using a predicate already in Prolog. I need to come up with a new one (like redundant/1 or something of that nature). Is anybody able to help?

Comment: Can you make any attempts at all? Is this for homework?

Comment: What sorts of predicates are considered "related" to `findall/3`? Are you allowed to use `member/2`? Just write a version that uses `member/2` then write your own `member/2`. It's fairly trivial.

Comment: Just reimplement `findall`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

One funny way to do it: sort the list with `sort/2`, that removes duplicates. Check if length of the initial list is greater than length of the sorted list.

```
redundant(List) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    length(List, A),
    length(Sorted, B),
    A > B.
```

Comment: No I cannot use code that Prolog already has built in. I came up with something like this :
redundant(X,X).
redundant([X|L]) :- red(X,L).
redundant([_|L]) :- redundant(L).
red(X,[X|_]).
red(X,[_|L]) :- red(X,L).

but it shows error in Prolog.

Comment: Update the question (or create a new one) with the code you attempted and more clear description what can be used and what can not.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ambiguity in your question: What do you mean by repeated elements? Should they be equal according to `(=)/2` (logical equality), `(==)/2` (syntactical equality), or `(=:=)/2` (arithmetical equality).

I will assume the first.

Taking a grammatical stance:

```
contains_duplicate(L) :-
    phrase( ( ..., [E], ..., [E], ... ), L).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Now, we can not only test a concrete list with some elements, but we can even ask general questions (I will use GNU-Prolog here, because of its comprehensive output):

```
| ?- contains_duplicate(L).
L = [A,A] ? a
L = [A,A,_]
L = [A,A,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_,_,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]
L = [A,A,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_] ...
```

So Prolog gives us all lists with the first two elements as duplicates. Where are the other possibilities? Unfortunately, they are hidden "behind" this infinite sequence of answers. But we have luck, we can do a **fair enumeration** of all answers like so:

```
| ?- length(L,_),contains_duplicate(L).
L = [A,A] ? a
L = [A,A,_]
L = [A,_,A]
L = [_,A,A]
L = [A,A,_,_]
L = [A,_,A,_]
L = [A,_,_,A]
L = [_,A,A,_]
L = [_,A,_,A]
L = [_,_,A,A]
L = [A,A,_,_,_] ...
```